# Store PHP Output To File?

Tags: php, cron, output

I'm working on a cron php script which will run once a day.  Because it runs this way, the output from the file can't be seen.

I could literally write all the messages I want into a variable, appending constantly information I want to be written to file, but this would be very tedious and I have a hunch not necessary.

Is there a PHP command to tell the write buffer to write to a log file somewhere? Is there a way to get access to what has been sent to the buffer already so that I can see the messages my script makes.

For example lets say the script says

**PHP:**

```
<?
  echo 'hello there';
  echo 'hello world';
?>
```

It should output to a file saying: 'hello therehello world';

Any ideas? Is this possible?

I'm already aware of

```
file_put_contents('log.txt', 'some data', FILE_APPEND);
```

This is dependent upon 'some data', when I don't know what 'some data' is unless I put it in a variable.  I'm trying to catch the results of whatever PHP has outputted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may want to redirect your output in `crontab`:

```
php /path/to/php/file.php >> log.txt
```

Or use PHP with, for example, [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file_put_contents):

```
file_put_contents('log.txt', 'some data', FILE_APPEND);
```

If you want to capture all PHP output, then use [`ob_`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) function, like:

```
ob_start();
/*
We're doing stuff..
stuff
...
and again
*/
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); //here, output is cleaned. You may want to flush it with ob_end_flush()
file_put_contents('log.txt', $content, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Here is the thing, 'some data' in your example would have to be a collection of all the outputs, is there a way to get access to whatever has currently been 'echoed' by PHP?

Comment: The crontab idea is good except, I don't have access to tell the crontab to write its results to file since I'm on a shared server.  Why I was looking for this solution.

Comment: awesome, that is what I was looking for, thanks.  Will accept answer soon, it's forcing me to wait 7 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ob_start() to store script output into buffer. See [php documentation ob_get_clean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

```
  <?php

  ob_start();

  echo "Hello World";

  $out = ob_get_clean();
  $out = strtolower($out);

  var_dump($out);
  ?>
```

Comment: ob_get_clean is useful if I need to print out the state of the PHP at different times since it clears the buffer for you, good to know +1

Answer (score 0):

If You're using cron I suppose that You run this on a Unix machine so:

One of approach is to write everything You want to `stdout` stream so in Unix You may grab this output to a file:

in php script:

```
$handle = fopen("php://stdout","w");

fwrite($handle,"Hello world"); // Hello world will be written to console
```

in cron job grab this output to a file:

```
@hourly php /var/www/phpscript.php >> /path/to/your/outputfile.txt
```

**Notice:** `>>` operator will append to a file and `>` operator will overwrite file by new data. File will be created automatically by first write

So everything you put to fwrite call as second argument will be placed in `/path/to/your/outputfile.txt`

You may call fwrite as many time as you want. Don't forget to close handler by `fclose($handle);`